# such a simple code of php is printing weird things out.i m not able to figure out why is this happening?

Tags: php, output

php code to print simple strings!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
<body>

<?php
$color="red";  //just a simple variable//
echo "My car is " . $color . "<br>";
echo "My house is " . $color . "<br>";
  echo "My boat is " . $color. "<br>";
 ?>

</body>
</html><!end of html>
```

the above code gives erroneous output.what could be the possible reason? 
     output:

"; echo "My house is " . $color . "
"; echo "My boat is " . $color. "
"; ?>

Comment: Are your running this through a webserver? And is the extension of the file .php?

Comment: your PHP is not running

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
<body>

<?php
$color="red";  //just a simple variable//
echo "My car is " . $color . "<br>";
echo "My house is " . $color . "<br>";
  echo "My boat is " . $color. "<br>";
 ?>

</body>
</html><!end of html>
```

save as

```
demo.php in htdocs
```

execute `http://localhost/demo.php`